# Parameterization of Curves and Surfaces

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, parametric, parametrization

I would like to know if the following settings are correct:

a) **Parameterization of Curve:**

Given the curve $C = \{(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \,|\, x^2 + y^2 = e^3\}$ I want to find a parameterization for it.

My proposed parameterization is as follows: Let $x = r \cos(\theta)$ and $y = r \sin(\theta)$, where $r$ is a positive parameter and $\theta$ is an angle parameter. Then:

$x^2 + y^2 = r^2(\cos^2(\theta) + \sin^2(\theta)) = r^2 = e^3$

So, $r = e^{3/2}$ is a constant. The parameterization of $C$ becomes:

$C(t) = (e^{3/2} \cos(t), e^{3/2} \sin(t), z)$

Here, $t$ is the parameter, and $z$ can be any real number since it's not restricted by the equation $x^2 + y^2 = e^3$.

b) **Parameterization of Surface:**

For the surface $S = \{(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \,|\, x^2 + y^2 = e^z\}$, I'd like to establish a parameterization.

I propose the following parameterization:
$S(u, v) = (e^{u/2} \cos(v), e^{u/2} \sin(v), u)$

Here, $u$ and $v$ are the parameters, and $u$ can be any real number since it's not restricted by the equation $x^2 + y^2 = e^z$.

c) **Tangent Plane to $S$ at $(0, 1, 0)$:**

To determine the tangent plane to the surface $S$ at the point $(0, 1, 0)$, we need to calculate the gradient of the function $F(x, y, z) = x^2 + y^2 - e^z$ and then evaluate it at $(0, 1, 0)$.

The gradient is:
$\nabla F(x, y, z) = (2x, 2y, -e^z)$

Evaluating this gradient at $(0, 1, 0)$, we get:
$\nabla F(0, 1, 0) = (0, 2, -1)$

So, the normal vector to the tangent plane at $(0, 1, 0)$ is $(0, 2, -1)$. Using the point-normal form of the equation of a plane, the equation of the tangent plane is:
$2(y - 1) - z = 0$

d) **Parameterization of the Surface Obtained by Rotating $C$:**

Consider the curve $C = \{(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \,|\, z = y^4\}$. I want to parameterize the surface $S$ that is obtained by rotating $C$ around the z-axis.

I suggest the following parameterization:
$S(r, \theta, z) = (r \cos(\theta), r \sin(\theta), z^{1/4})$

Here, $r$ and $\theta$ define the position in the xy-plane, and $z$ is determined by $z = y^4$, so $y = z^{1/4}$.

Please provide help, feedback and improvements if needed. Thank you!

Comment: In part (d), the set $C$ describes a surface. Are you missing a condition on $x$? Also, your parametrization of $S$ (same part) should consist of $2$ variables, not $3$.

Comment: @user170231 The parameterization can be given as: S(r,θ)=(0,r cos⁡(θ),  r sin⁡(θ))?

Comment: How do you know $x=0$?

Comment: @user170231 because x isn't in the expression

Comment: But the equation you have for $C$ in part (a) also doesn't include a variable, and yet you've chosen $z\neq0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answers for the first three parts are fine.

In part (d), the given set does not describe a curve in $\Bbb R^3$ but a surface. To picture it yourself, imagine the $y,z$ plane and plot the curve $z=y^4$. This equations holds for all $x$, so if you add the $x$ axis to your picture you "stretch" the curve out to get a sort of parabolic cylinder:

[image]

If we fix $x=0$, the surface "shrinks" back down to a curve, which is probably what the exercise intended considering the axis of revolution:

[image]

Take this to be $C$, and consider the half with positive $y$ coordinate. Rotating any point on $C$ about the $z$ axis traces out a circle of radius equal to $y$ in the plane $z=y^4$. (One such circle is shown at $z=0.5$.)

[image]

Now introducing $\theta$, we can parameterize by

$$S(y,\theta) = \left(y \cos \theta, y \sin \theta, y^4\right)$$